# how to run flutter methods in background?

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, background

I am trying to call the method continuously but when I lock the screen of my phone or press the home button the method not get called again. so plz suggest how to run the method in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a plugin such as https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

There are other similar plugins you may try.

"Background Fetch is a very simple plugin which will awaken an app in the background about every 15 minutes, providing a short period of background running-time. This plugin will execute your provided callbackFn whenever a background-fetch event occurs."

Comment: i had tried this plugin.

but i get this error after installing this plugin.

Comment: What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch:+ as no versions of com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/

Comment: the above was my error i got while running my app

Comment: I have same issue

Comment: @KaranJain You have to follow the setup instructions on the GitHub page very carefully.  I had this issue even after thinking I'd followed the instructions but it turned out I had modified the wrong repository section of build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You will use android alarm manager for android apps using Flutter

https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager

```
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';

void printHello() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
  print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId} function='$printHello'");
}

main() async {
  final int helloAlarmID = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(...);
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), helloAlarmID, printHello);
}
```

As you can see, is simple, you only need to create a function and call it using AndroidAlarmManager.periodic, remember to add permissions on your android manifest.

If you need a solution for Android and iOS you can use platform channels https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels
you can use platform channels to call native code from android an iOS, for example you can create native background services and call it from Flutter.